# PL/SQL: Is it possible to have a nested table with multiple columns?

Tags: plsql

I want to do something like this:

type tab_imb is table of (cod number, job varchar2(10));

but SQL doesn't let me. Can I declare a nested table with multiple columns in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Yes you can, sort of, you cannot do it directly.  What you need is create an object that defines your "inner" column definitions then create a collection (table) of that object type.
So at the schema level:

```
create type imb_obj_type as object(cod number,  job varchar2(20));
create type tab_imb is table of imb_obj_type;

declare 
   v_imb tab_imb := tab_imb(); 
begin 
   v_imb.extend(2);
   v_imb(1) := imb_obj_type(1,'Lead');
   v_imb(2) := imb_obj_type(2,'Developer'); 
   
   dbms_output.put_line('----- Job List -----'); 
   for indx in 1 .. v_imb.count
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line('cod=>' || v_imb(indx).cod || ', ' ||
                           'Job=>' || ', ' || v_imb(indx).job
                          ); 
   end loop; 
end ;
```

At the procedure or anonymous block you can use the above or define a record:

```
declare 
   type imb_rec is record(cod number, job varchar2(20));
   type tab_imb is table of imb_rec;
   v_imb tab_imb := tab_imb(); 
begin 
   v_imb.extend(2);
   v_imb(1).cod := 1;
   v_imb(1).job := 'Lead';
   v_imb(2).cod := 2;
   v_imb(2).job := 'Developer'; 
   
   dbms_output.put_line('----- Job List -----'); 
   for indx in 1 .. v_imb.count
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line('cod=>' || v_imb(indx).cod || ', ' ||
                           'Job=>' || ', ' || v_imb(indx).job
                          ); 
   end loop; 
end ;
```